# Не могу добавить в вектор умный указатель

Tags: c++, vector, stl, smart-pointer

Имеется класс MyClass, разумеется с конструктором, нужно создать вектор умных указателей на объекты этого класса. Сам указатель создается, но при попытке добавления в вектор вылезает ошибка . Что я упустил?

```
#include <memory>
#include  <vector>

using namespace std;
Int main()
{
    vector<unique_ptr<MyClass>> vectorPtr;
    unique_ptr<MyClass> p1(new MyClass);
    // до этого момента всё в порядке
    vectorPtr.push_back(p1);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::unique_ptr` не имеет конструктора копирования, поэтому, чтобы поместить его в вектор, его нужно *переместить* туда:

```
vectorPtr.push_back(std::move(p1));
```

Или так:

```
vectorPtr.push_back(std::make_unique<MyClass>())
```

Либо же создавать прямо в векторе:

```
vectorPtr.emplace_back(new MyClass);
```